# What does "for x in sys.stdin" do exactly?

Tags: python, string, stdin

Simple question here, but I can't find a definitive answer. I'm writing some python code and I'm confused as to what this line does exactly:

```
a = []
for x in sys.stdin:
    c = x.split()
    a.extend(c)
```

When I run it, it defaults to making a list of words, but why is that? Why does python default to words instead of lines, or even characters from the stdin? I know about the readlines and readline methods, but I'm confused as to what exactly this code is doing with the stdin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

File objects, including `sys.stdin`, are iterable. Looping over a file object yields *lines*, so the text from that file up to the next line separator.

It never produces words. Your code produces words because you explicitly split each line:

```
c = x.split()
```

`str.split()` without arguments splits on *arbitrary-length whitespace sequences* (removing any whitespace from the start and end), effectively giving you a list of words, which are then added to the `a` list with `list.extend()`.

Comment: I get it now. I had strip() and split() confused, was wondering why a method to remove trailing whitespace was resulting in words. Thanks for the answer.